# Zend Framework Session issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

Problem with zend application . When I log in into my application session starts and stores in /tmp folder . but when I redirect to other page it returns null.

Here is the session code I use:

http://pastie.org/4099332

when I redirect to my home page " $authNamespace->userData " returns null.

I am using ubuntu 12.04.

Please help.

Comment: The php.ini directive display_error is enabled?

Comment: what does validateUser() return? `$result = $userModel->validateUser($data);` also you may consider setting the session in the model and just returning a boolean to the controller.

Comment: How are you accessing the Session data on your home page ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you started the session in your bootstrap?

```
Zend_Session::start();
```

Comment: This would be important for the way @Sirajus Salayhin is trying to use Zend_session as he is calling session after headers have been sent. http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.advanced_usage.html#zend.session.advanced_usage.starting_a_session

Comment: No I did this (Zend_Session::start();) but same error .

$result = $userModel->validateUser($data); this method works fine.